# Apache Nifi web interface the "execution error" attribute of the ExecuteStreamCommand processor is truncated

Tags: apache-nifi

Currently I am using the Apache Nifi to design a flow to ingest data from oracle database to Hadoop environment of our company.

I have met some error when execute the sqoop command by using the ExecuteStreamCommand processor. But when I go to the queue info of the error thread. I found that **the error message has been truncated** and I couldn`t see the full error message to let me find out the problem of causing error when executing the sqoop command. Is there any way to see the **full execution.error attribute without truncate it**? Thank you in advance.

What I have tried is to set the Max Attribute Length to 10000 and I found the output execution.error is still truncated...